# ¿insulto oral debe estar límitado a una expresión?

Tags: definiciones

Conozco el término insulto como para referirse a una expresión ofensiva, ejemplos de insultos:

- Tonto
- Sin respeto
- Cabeza de chorlito
- simio sin cerebro

Según la definición de **insultar**:

> Ofender con palabras o acciones.

Y según la definición de **insulto**:

> Ofensa, especialmente con palabras hirientes, injuria.

En ambas definiciones se habla de "palabras", pero no me queda claro si sería correcto considerar una frase con un adverbio relativo como un insulto, por ejemplo, una comparación, como en los siguientes textos:

> "Gritas como niño" (que grita muy agudo)

> "Bailas como guardia real" (que es muy tieso)

> "Escribes como doctor" (que escribe mal, no se le entiende)

Ninguna de esas palabras por si sola es un insulto, pero, ¿es correcto decir que la construcción completa de estas frases son insultos? si bien, son ofensivas, ya que indican a la otra persona que hace algo mal, no son una "palabra" (o expresión), y es aquí donde sale mi duda respecto a la acepción "literal" del termino insultar/insulto.

*Resumiendo:*

¿Sería correcto decir que la frase "*Escribes como doctor*", es **UN** insulto?

*Preguntado de otra forma*

El texto "Escribes como doctor" ¿puede ser en algún contexto un ejemplo de la palabra insulto?

Comment: Depende de a quién se lo digas. Si a un calígrafo, o a un maestro de primaria (que se supone que deben escribir claramente) les dices que escriben como médicos, ciertamente pueden tomarlo a mal, como que los estás descalificando.

Comment: Imaginemos que es para que intensionalmente se lo tome mal y lo estamos descalificando, dejando de lado si se lo toma bien o mal, mi pregunta va más por el lado de si el texto completo (2 palabras comparadas) puede ser "literalmente" un ejemplo correcto del término "insulto" o es una ofensa de otro tipo.

Comment: Por favor, "intencionalmente" se escribe con C (verla escrita son S es casi un insulto :) ). En respuesta a tu pregunta, creo que la línea entre ofensa e insulto es muy delgada. Es una cuestión muy subjetiva. Si a un tenor le dices que canta como un niño, ciertamente lo tomará como un insulto.

Comment: Un insulto es una percepción, a veces _subjetiva_ por parte de quien lo recibe, y se puede debatir hasta qué punto requiere de cierta *intencionalidad* por parte de quien lo produce. Una palabra (simple o malsonante), una fase, un gesto o incluso la falte de ellos, puede considerarse un insulto. "Escribes como doctor", o "pegas como una niña" o incluso "pegas como un _marica_" pueden ser insultos, insultos graves o bromas bien recibidas, dependiendo del contexto, intencionalidad y confianza y relación de los interlocutores. Mi respuesta sería que dependen de la **intención** del hablante.

Comment: ok, no se como explicar que no estoy preguntando sobre la intencionalidad (del emisor) o la percepción (del receptor), sino sobre como debe ser construido el texto para que pueda ser insulto o no :( pero creo que Diego parece indicar que una frase si puede serlo... ya se, preguntado de otra forma: el texto "Escribes como doctor" ¿puede ser en algún contexto un ejemplo de la palabra insulto?

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulto

Comment: "Escribes como doctor"  puede ser un comentario (hiriente) si solo estás valorando la caligrafía de alguien. Puede ser un insulto si lo que quieres es menospreciar a la persona. Un insulto no está limitado a una palabra.

Comment: Un insulto puede ser cualquier cosa. Todo depende de la situacón del locutor y del interlocutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el DLE, [insultar](https://dle.rae.es/insultar) es:

> 1. tr. Ofender a alguien provocándolo e irritándolo con palabras o acciones.

Es decir, un insulto es la acción de usar **palabras** (una o varias) para **ofender**. Pueden ser cualquier tipo de palabras, siempre que sean usadas para ofender. Nada en esa definición dice que las palabras tengan que ser insultos individualmente. Por tanto, decir

> Bailas como un guardia real

es un insulto si esa secuencia de palabras se utiliza para ofender.

En la definición del DLE, el requerimiento de "intencionalidad" no está claro a primera vista. Sin embargo, la definición habla de "provocar", y la definición de "[provocar](https://dle.rae.es/provocar?m=form)" es

> 2. tr. Buscar una reacción de enojo en alguien irritándolo o estimulándolo con palabras u obras. U. t. c. intr.

lo cual requiere intencionalidad. Por tanto, un insulto debe tener la intención de ofender, y además conseguirlo. El tipo de palabras o hechos que se use es irrelevante.

Answer (score 1):

**INSULTO**

---

- Cuestión; "Escribes como doctor". ¿Puede ser en algún contexto un ejemplo de la palabra insulto?

---

- *Traidor, descompuesto, villano, infacundo, deslenguado, atrevido, desdichado, maldiciente, canalla, rústico, patán, malmirado, bellaco, socarrón, mentecato y hediondo*" (De Don Quijote a Sancho Panza).
- "*Cuesco de dátil*" (Don Quijote de La Mancha)
- ¡*Oh malaventurado escudero, alma de cántaro, corazón de alcornoque, de entrañas guijeñas y apedernaladas!.. ¡Ladrón, desuellacaras,... enemigo del género humano*!" (Don Quijote de La Mancha)
- "*Tiene más cabellos que talento, y más defectos que cabellos, y más riquezas que defectos*" (Dos Caballeros de Verona) William Shakespeare
- "*Hablas una cantidad infinita de nada*"(El Mercader de Venecia) William Shakespeare
- "*Deseo que seamos los mejores desconocidos*" William Shakespeare
- "*Eres un tumor, una llaga que supura, una úlcera inflamada en mi sangre corrompida*" (El Rey Lear) William Shakespeare

---

El insulto como uso social que cumple una función dentro de una comunidad. Parece una cuestión fácil, pero por contra puede ser en sí misma extensa y precisa, según los casos, de un gran análisis.

En los estudios pragmáticos, el insulto, se ha considerado, por algunos autores, un acto poco serio, puesto al mismo lado que la ironía ó el humor, donde la base se encuentra en arremeter contra otro.

Por otro lado, otra serie de autores consideran al insulto como un conjunto de símbolos que son importantes para entender aspectos de la comunicación humana.

Según lo establecido, el insulto proviene *"del verbo latino "insultare" con significado  'asaltar' en sentido propio, es decir que viene de saltus (salto), y 'desafiar', 'insultar', en sentido figurado por ser un salto que se da contra otra persona*".

El insulto siempre hay que analizarlo, por una parte, a partir del vocabulario social con que se interpreta (pues los términos en desuso ó antiguos, pueden ser altamente ofensivos, pero sin valor en la actualidad), y por otra, siempre hay que observa los contextos socio-culturales que los acogen.

Los rasgos insultante se caracterizan por contener aspectos que son, tanto para el que los enuncia como para el que los recibe, ser poseedores de atributos negativos, pues fuera, aislados ó en comunidades distintas, pueden perder su valor negativo y por contra adquirir un valor positivo.

Dentro de la gran variedad de formas y sentidos sobre el "Insulto", existe una extensa variedad, esto es solo un pequeño resumen;

- Las señales, accidentales ó intencionadas (Insultantes).
- Acciones ó conductas realizadas que por sí mismas pueden considerarse insultantes.
- Las unidades léxicas simples
  / Malas palabras (obscenas, sexuales, tabúes...)
  / Eufemismos (forma de comunicar algo feo u ofensivo de una forma más suave)
  / Disfemismos (expresión deliberadamente despectiva o insultante que se emplea en lugar de otra más neutral)
  / Monosémica ( palabras que tienen un solo significado) y Polisémicas (varios significados).
  / Derivados (Una simple palabra léxica ó compuesta descalificante)
  Cavazanjas ( referido a personas que no le gusta hacer nada, son muy vagas o no sirven para otra cosa).
  Chupacables, Chupacabras, Gilipollas, Pagafantas...
- Unidades léxicas complejas

  ```
   Bajo la forma /A SER B   - Tu eres un gallina
                            - Eso será tu madre
                            - Tu padre es un cobarde

   Bajo la forma / A Más QUE/TAN B

                             - Pablo eres más pesado que un cura.
                             - Rocío es más fea que tirar la basura
                             - Ese es tan gilipollas como su padre

   Bajo la forma / Cagarse en
                             - Me cago en toda tu familia
                             - Me cago en la leche de tu hermana
  ```
- Sin agravio aparente

  ```
                             - Cementerio de Canelones (Referidos a un gordo)
                             - Tobogán de piojos (referidos a un calvo)
  ```
- Específicos

  ```
                             - Tienes la cara de un limón podrido (mustia)
                             - Basura con patas (Cucaracha)
  ```
- Interminables o añadidos...

Eres más feo que pegarle a un padre, (otra persona añade), con un calcetín, (otro añade), a las cuatro de la mañana, (otro añade) de un domingo.

"Eres más feo que pegarle a un padre con un calcetín a las cuatro de la mañana de un Domingo".

---

El problema del "Insulto", es que en las descripciones que se hacen no están reflejadas las diversas disciplinas de comunicación que intervienen a las que somos normalmente ajenos, así la antropología, la sociolingüística, la pragmática, etc, no son capaces de distinguir la acción racional de la irracional.

La variedad y complejidad de la inventiva que puede utilizar la mente para insultar entendido como desagradar, molestar, ofender a otro, es infinita. El Insulto que más queda en la memoria el aquel que es inteligente y oportuno, o tan fuera de contexto, que hacen que se sonrojen ó se rían.

---

"Escribes como un doctor"

Así en el insulto se trata de herir a otro, normalmente utilizando lo que más daño pueda causarle, desafortunadamente muchas veces no es una cuestión de ingenio, mal gusto ó inteligencia, sino de ofender. En este sentido, depende entonces, igualmente del contexto. Si a un niño de primaria le dices "*Escribes como un doctor*", obviamente interpretará que no escribe adecuadamente y será humillante y ofensivo para él. Sin embargo, si a un estudiante de carrera en 4º de medicina, le dices, "*Escribes como un doctor*", seguro que su percepción de la misma expresión puede llegar hasta ser positiva, pues el mismo hecho que caracteriza a los médicos de escribir mal, puede ser valorado como positivo y como algo cercano a la meta a conseguir, donde esta misma apreciación, enfocada desde el gremio de médicos, es parte característica de esa comunidad.

De esta manera, para ser considerado un "Insulto" se puede llamar a un médico "matasanos" ó "analfabeto" a un gran editor, pero si eso no les afecta, será un "*Insulto sin Efecto*". Para considerar, una expresión "Insulto" en su sentido más puro, habrá que apuntar hacia el lugar donde se puedan alterar las percepciones de la persona sobre aquello que se utiliza para increparle, ya que en la mayoría de los casos confundimos el mismo insulto con la rabia que podemos sentir al canalizar ó comunicar un sentimiento de frustración .

.